# LSF Job Array in Make File

Tags: makefile, lsf

I am running an LSF job array to create a target in a makefile.
However as soon as the array is submitted make considers the command for the target to be executed, and throws an error as the target does not exist.

How can I force make to wait until the completion of the LSF job array before moving onto other dependent targets?

Example:

```
all: final.txt

first_%.txt:
    bsub -J" "jarray[1-100]" < script.sh

final.txt: first_%.txt
    cat first_1.txt first_50.txt first_100.txt > final.txt
```

Unfortunately the -K flag isn't supported for job arrays.

Comment: Does it need to be a makefile?  Potentially you could use job dependencies a do the `cat ... > final.txt` in a job. Or perhaps you could keep the makefile and use the `bsub -K` for the final job. That way the rule for final.txt will still block until its done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `bsub -K` which should force bsub to stay in the foreground until the job completes.

**Edit**

Since the option isn't supported on arrays, I think you'll have to submit your array as separate jobs, something like:

```
for i in `seq 1 100`; do 
            export INDEX=$i
            bsub -K < script.sh & 
done
wait
```

You'll have to pass the index to your script manually instead of using the job array index.

Comment: bsub -K doesnt work on job arrays. "Job array doesn't support -K option. Job not submitted."

Comment: aha, in that case you won't much like my other solution which I'll add but it's all I can think of...

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the `bsub` command to wait for the job to complete.  I have never used it, but according to [the man page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSETD4_9.1.3/lsf_command_ref/bsub.heading_options.1.html) you can add the `-K` option to do this.

Comment: bsub -K doesnt work on job arrays. "Job array doesn't support -K option. Job not submitted."

Comment: That's too bad.  Well, you have to find a way to have your recipe wait until everything is done.  There's nothing `make` can do to help here: you'll need to solve that via some scripting in your recipe or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the bsub job array without -K option and then use bwait -w  command. It will wait until this jobid will be finished.

> bsub .....(your bsub command without -K option.)

Job <4637108> is submitted to queue

> bwait -w 4637108    (It will stay on terminal until the job id is finished.)

4637108: Wait condition satisfied